# Having trouble with release variables

Tags: tfs

I am trying to use the `Release.RequestedForEmail` release variable in one of my release definitions to pass to a Powershell script, but I am not receiving the value. When I looked at the logs-> Initialize Job task, I don't even see that variable being defined.

I am using a Powershell script to send some email to the user that triggered the release, he/she needs to receive the email in order to approve/deny the next manual intervention task.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is weird since this release variable exists under [Default and custom release variables and debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables) .

As a workaround you can use RELEASE.REQUESTEDFOR variable and customize the email adress .

I don't know if this is what you are looking for but it works for me.

**UPDATE :**

i wrote the following function which gets user id and return the email address from TFS.

```
function getEmailAdressByUserID($userID)
{

  $tfsURL = "http://{server}:{port}/{organization}/{project}"

 (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$tfsURL/_apis/Identities/$userID" -UseDefaultCredentials).Properties.Mail

}
```

Usage :

```
getEmailAdressByUserID -userID $(RELEASE.DEPLOYMENT.REQUESTEDFORID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I added my preferred email in here and it worked out perfectly

[image]